# ¿Qué debería hacerse con las respuestas con baja puntuación?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, convenciones-sociales, votos-negativos, respuestas-borradas

Me he encontrado el caso de un usuario con buena reputación que elimina las respuestas cuando recibe votos negativos y un comentario a su respuesta de por qué su respuesta no es la adecuada.

¿No creéis que es mejor dejar la respuesta, a pesar de ser errónea?

Mi teoría es que esto se hace simplemente para recuperar la reputación y creo que este tipo de comportamiento se tendría que poder reportar, porque los comentarios de la respuesta errónea pueden ayudar al OP.

En mi caso creo que es preferible editar y rectificar.

Comment: `porque los comentarios de la respuesta errónea, pueden ayudar al OP` ... ¿ No ayudaría mucho mas **una respuesta correcta** ?. Eso es lo que nos diferencia de un *foro*: información válida **localizada en un sitio**, y no tener que seguir el hilo de 17 respuestas, por varias páginas, para encontrar lo que buscamos.

Comment: Es normal eliminar preguntas que tienen votos negativos. De hecho, existe [una medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) que fomenta que los posts de baja calidad sean eliminados. Si una respuesta tiene votos negativos significa que varios usuarios del sitio consideran que no es correcta, o que no tiene la suficiente calidad para el sitio, y no tiene excesivo sentido que se mantenga. De todas maneras, es obviamente una decision libre del autor. Otra cosa es que la respuesta tenga votos positivos o sea aceptada, en esos casos el sistema no permite eliminarla.

Comment: Buenas Macaroni. Eliminar respuestas para recuperar reputación no es dañino si la respuesta es incorrecta ya que no es de ayuda. Si algo se ha sacado en claro de la respuesta errónea, se puede resumir en los comentarios bajo la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Yo creo que lo mejor para todos es dejar respuestas buenas y útiles :) Entiendo que pueda ser extraño lo de borrar respuestas, pero entiendo que es por buena fe: se da cuenta de que está mal y la borra. Probablemente sería bueno que indicara un "ostras es verdad, la he liado, borro" o bien "tienes razón, lo edito", pero no creo que haya que juzgarlo severamente si es con buena fe.

Comment: Creo que se están mezclando dos conceptos diferentes: respuestas erróneas y malas soluciones. Mientras que la primera es normal que reciba votos negativos y acabe eliminada, puede que con la segunda no ocurra eso. En alguna ocasión he publicado respuestas del tipo: "se podría hacer de este otro modo, pero no lo hagas así por xyz". Si la respuesta con una mala solución ha sido a propósito y sirve para educar o explicar por qué una mal patrón es malo, lo consideraría una buena respuesta aunque lo que se exponga sea una mala solución.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cuando vengo a SOes (o cualquier otro sitio de SE) buscando información, considero las respuestas erróneas como ruido. Una respuesta mala puede serlo por muchos motivos:

- el usuario no entendió correctamente la pregunta.
- está respondiendo a otra pregunta y se confundió de pestaña.
- realmente no es una respuesta y no es más que un comentario "a mí también me pasa".
- es otra pregunta
- el OP no sabe editar la pregunta y quiere añadir más información, con lo que lo hace usando una respuesta.
- es vandalismo.
- está aplicando un antipatrón: la respuesta soluciona el problema pero crea otro.

Excepto el último caso, que se podría poner de *ejemplo de lo que no hay que hacer* como apéndice a una buena respuesta, todo lo demás debería ser borrado por que no aporta absolutamente nada al OP o a quien venga después buscando soluciones/conocimiento.

En SE en general se busca la calidad, por lo que es importante tener una relación ruido/información lo más baja posible.

Por otro lado, el que recuperes la reputación perdida al borrar la respuesta/pregunta, está hecho así a propósito, no es un fallo del sistema. Se promueve que quites las malas respuestas/preguntas.

Comment: Interesante reflexión, gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 6):

Cuando una respuesta es errónea(como mas de una ocasión me ha pasado) se hace por las siguientes razones

- Evitas confundir a usuarios novatos con contenido equivocado
- Puedes recuperar la respuesta después si la editas y aportas una solución que no ha sido propuesta antes
- Ayudas a mantener la calidad del sitio evitando llenarlo de contenido que lejos de ayudar puede ser contraproducente
- El sistema tiene la inteligencia suficiente para detectar cuando un usuario tiene como comportamiento serial *eliminar respuestas suyas* de manera reiterada y se lo hace saber a algún moderador

Si se dejara contenido de baja calidad el sitio sería una fuente de consulta de baja calidad pues no se sabría cual respuesta es la adecuada si la que esta como aceptada o aquella que solo tiene 1 voto negativo, pero que si los usuarios votaran mas, seguro tendría muchos mas indicando que no es contenido adecuado